# Árvore de decisão em R (trava)

Tags: r

Estou tentando fazer uma árvore de decisão em R.

Nada profissional, estudo autodidata.

Mas na chamada do rpart , o R na minha máquina trava (rpart).

*Deixei rodando , fui ver um jogo de futebol na tv e ao final ainda rodava ...*

Pergunta , tem erro no script ou minha máquina é pouco para a coisa ?

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
 Processador Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2430M CPU @ 2.40GHz 6,9 4,9 
 Memória (RAM) 6,00 GB 7,4 
 Elementos gráficos Intel(R) HD Graphics 3000 4,9 
 Gráficos de jogos 3281 Total de megabytes disponíveis na memória gráfica 6,3 
 Disco rígido primário 467GB Livre(s) (581GB no Total) 5,9 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------





library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(factoextra)
library(ggplot2)
library(rpart)
library(rpart.plot) 

##exemplo adaptado de
##https://www.guru99.com/r-decision-trees.html 

set.seed(808)
rm(fut) 
rm(fut2) 
fut <-  read.csv("C:\\R_Estudos\\futebol\\prmlplayers.csv")  
##fonte
##https://footystats.org/c-dl.php?type=players&comp=1625

##fut2 <-fut %>% select(2,7,8,9,12,16)

fut2 <-fut %>% select(2,7,9,12,16)

#transformar a varriavel numerica em qualitativa , reduzir escopo
fut2 <- fut2 %>%  mutate(fxgoals = case_when(goals_overall == 0  ~ "0",
                                             goals_overall > 0 & goals_overall < 4 ~ "1-3",
                                             goals_overall > 3 & goals_overall < 7 ~ "4-6",
                                             goals_overall > 6 & goals_overall < 9 ~ "7-8",
                                             goals_overall > 8 ~ "9 ou mais",
                                             TRUE ~ "none"))

fut2 <- fut2 %>%  select(-goals_overall)

shuffle_index <- sample(1:nrow(fut2))
head(shuffle_index)

fut2 <- fut2[shuffle_index, ]
head(fut2)


create_train_test <- function(data, size = 0.8, train = TRUE) {
  n_row = nrow(data)
  total_row = size * n_row
  train_sample <- 1: total_row
  if (train == TRUE) {
    return (data[train_sample, ])
  } else {
    return (data[-train_sample, ])
  }
}

data_train <- create_train_test(fut2, 0.8, train = TRUE)
data_test <- create_train_test(fut2, 0.8, train = FALSE)
dim(data_train)

prop.table(table(data_train$fxgoals))
prop.table(table(data_test$fxgoals))

#trava aqui
chute <- rpart(fxgoals~., data = data_train, method = 'class') 
rpart.plot(chute, extra = 106)
```

Comment: Vejo dois problemas. O primeiro, que não tem a ver com sua pergunta, é o sample. A função de create_train_test não faz uma amostragem correta. Mas isso não prejudica a execução, apenas a base estatística. Experimente `sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), nrow(data), replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.1,0.9))` O problema do tempo é devido à inclusão de países (67), o que prejudica a árvore, o viés estatístico (215 ingleses x < 5 de (50 paises)) e consequentemente o tempo. Exclua os países e o tempo fica imediato.

Comment: @Daniel Ikenaga , muito grato , vou testar isto hoje ainda.

Comment: Cheguei a achar que os gols feitos seria o problema por isto fiz a variável agrupando, mas creio de dar com burros n'agua faça parte

Comment: Gostaria de saber porque o post teve dois votos para fechamento.

Comment: Suprimindo o país , executou , gerou a "tree". Grato !